# Bluemix / Watson Natural Language Processing invalid API Key

Tags: javascript, node.js, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, pubnub

Have searched, but can't find similar issues in the past year. I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](https://hackernoon.com/visualizing-trump-7e1cb5e55a78), but things seem to have changed since it was published in April. I've got the PubNub Modules built and have registered a Bluemix Watson account and set up a Natural Language Understanding Service.

It when I try to run the test package in PubNub, I receive the error:

23:24:12  js:

> [" TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined  at
>   Sentiment/IBM Watson.js:46:43   at process._tickCallback
>   (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)"] Error   at Sentiment/IBM
>   Watson.js:76:21   at process._tickCallback
>   (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)

23:24:13 js:

```
{ "body": "{ \"status\": \"ERROR\", \"statusInfo\": \"invalid-api-key\", \"usage\": \"By accessing AlchemyAPI or using information generated by AlchemyAPI, you are agreeing to be bound by the AlchemyAPI Terms of Use: http://www.alchemyapi.com/company/terms.html\", \"totalTransactions\": \"1\", \"language\": \"unknown\" }
```

The tutorial code for the api is this:

```
export default (request) => {
    // url for sentiment analysis api
    const apiUrl = 'https://gateway-a.watsonplatform.net/calls/text/TextGetTextSentiment';

    // api key
const apiKey = 'Your_API_Key';
```

but it seems as the the API format for Bluemix has changed since the tutorial was written. The Bluemix credentials are now in the format:

```
{
  "url": "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/natural-language-understanding/api",
  "username": "x",
  "password": "y"
}
```

As someone who comes from using R as a statistical calculator and just programmed his first (primitive) battleship game in Python last week, any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

As you can see:

> IBM Bluemix just announced the [retirement of the AlchemyAPI service](https://www.ibm.com/blogs/bluemix/2017/03/bye-bye-alchemyapi/).
>   They say to use instead the Natural Language Understanding service,
>   also under Watson.

Natural language understanding doesn't use API KEY like AlchemyAPI. When you create your service inside IBM Bluemix, you can saw in the Service Credentials your `username` and `password`:

[image]

So, for use Natural Language Understading with Javascript, you need to follow the API Reference:

```
var NaturalLanguageUnderstandingV1 = require('watson-developer-cloud/natural-language-understanding/v1.js');
var natural_language_understanding = new NaturalLanguageUnderstandingV1({
  'username': '{username}', //Service Credentials
  'password': '{password}', //Service Credentials
  'version_date': '2017-02-27'
});

var parameters = {
  'text': 'IBM is an American multinational technology company headquartered in Armonk, New York, United States, with operations in over 170 countries.',
  'features': {
    'entities': {
      'emotion': true,
      'sentiment': true,
      'limit': 2
    },
    'keywords': {
      'emotion': true,
      'sentiment': true,
      'limit': 2
    }
  }
}

natural_language_understanding.analyze(parameters, function(err, response) {
  if (err)
    console.log('error:', err);
  else
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));
});
```

- See the Official [API Reference](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/natural-language-understanding/api/v1/?node) using Node.js
- [Demo](https://natural-language-understanding-demo.mybluemix.net) to you saw how NLU API works.
- Migrating from [AlchemyAPI](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/natural-language-understanding/migrating.html).